# How do I retain the indentation of numbered lists?

Tags: html, css

How do you retain the indentation of numbered lists?  I have a page where the numbers are pushed off the page.  How can I prevent this?

```
<ol style="padding: 0">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: In what? HTML/CSS? Word? What code is related to this problem? Please be more *specific*.

Comment: @Doug.T: How do you know the author is not talking about MS-Word?

Comment: Please post your example html and css that are not working...

Comment: @BoltBait: Experience with what? That people asking the dumbest questions are usually posting questions about html/css? ;-)

Comment: Boy, somebody got up on the grumpy side of the bed this morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a CSS rule like this:

```
ol { margin-left: 30px; }
```

Here's some information about the [CSS box model](http://redmelon.net/tstme/box_model/).

Answer (score 1):

What about using:

```
li { list-style-position: outside; }
```